# calculus radical integration question

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Does anyone know how to calculate integral of $\sqrt{ 1-\cos (x)}$ ? I tried several methods resulting in $-2\sqrt2 \cos (x/2) + c$, but this is wrong in accordance with the text book, so i dont know how to proceed...

Comment: what is the answer according to your book?

Comment: This http://www5a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP13331e534d5bg42i56hh00003i45hi13dc67hdi0?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=49&w=148.&h=33.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int \sqrt{ 1-\cos (x)} dx &=  \int\sqrt 2 \left| \sin \left( \frac x 2 \right ) \right | dx\\ 
 &= -2\sqrt 2 \cos \left( \frac x 2 \right ) \mathrm{sgn} \left( \sin \left( \frac x 2 \right )\right)\\ 
 &= -2\sqrt 2 \cot \left( \frac x 2   \right ) \left| \sin \left( \frac x 2\right)\right|\\ 
 &=  -2  \cot \left(\frac x 2 \right )\sqrt{ 2\sin ^2 \left(\frac x 2 \right )}\\ 
 &= -2  \cot \left(\frac x 2 \right ) \sqrt{1 - \cos x}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\sqrt{1-\cos x} = \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x} \sqrt{1+\cos x}} {\sqrt{1+\cos x}} =\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}}{ \sqrt{1+\cos x}} = \frac{ \sin x}{\sqrt{1+\cos x}}$$

Here we used that $1+\cos x$ and $1-\cos x$ are nonnegative to combine the square roots.

Now you use the substitution $u = \cos x$.